# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray' - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter the `DF` by checking the `PCS` Column `if == 0` and `'ITEM DESC' =='ITEM XL'`. If the criteria is met, I will multiply it by the `BOX` value and multiply it by `48`.

DF

```
     ITEM DESC            PCS                   BOX
     ITEM S               12                     -   
     ITEM M               12                     -   
     ITEM L               12                     -   
     ITEM XS              12                     -   
     ITEM XL              0                      1
```

CODES

```py
    if DF[DF['PCS']==0] & DF[DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM XL'] :  
       DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 48   
    else:
       DF['PCS']
```

ERROR

```
      TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'
```

Comment: This isn't the right way to approach this, post your expected output as well

Comment: Why do you have `DatetimeArray`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you meant `all`:

```
if DF[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM XL')].all():  
   DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 48
```

Or `any`:

```
if DF[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM XL')].any():  
   DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 48
```

Or more probable that you want to do it to specific rows:

```
 DF.loc[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM XL'), 'PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 48
```

Comment: thanks ..I tried to used the aboved script and I got this error --> `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`

Comment: Sorry..  I Forgot to mentioned . What if  I selected other `ITEM DESC`

Comment: `if DF[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM S')].any():  
 DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 60
 elif DF[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM M')].any():
 DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 48
  elif DF[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM L')].any():
 DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 60                  
 elif DF[(DF['PCS']==0) & (DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM L ')].any():
 DF['PCS'] = DF['PCS'] * DF['BOX'] * 48
 else:  DF['PCS']`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.apply`

```
DF['PCS'] = DF.apply(lambda x: x.DF['PCS'] * x.DF['BOX'] * 48 if x.DF['PCS']==0 and x.DF['ITEM DESC']=='ITEM XL' else x.DF['PCS']==0, axis=1)
```